# Displaying data in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have a split view controller for iPad with a drill-down table on the left.  I am able to populate my first table view and when I click on a cell this takes me to my second table view.  I am able to see a count of records returned and the actual data I expect to see in the table view output in the command widow with the NSLog command.  What I don't see is the actual data in the table view.  Instead I see UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator for each row that is returned but no actual data.

I am using xib files and I have created this file for my products I want displayed in the drill-down.  In my Product.xib file I have the File's Owner Outlets as productsTableView linked to products (my UITableView control) and view linked to View.  Referencing Outlets for the View have dataSource linked to products, delegate linked to products and finally view linked to File's Owner.

Am I missing something here?  Like I said I get all the data back it just isn't binding to the grid.

```
@interface ProductViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
NSMutableArray *dataArray;
IBOutlet UITableView *productsTableView;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *productsTableView;

@end


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
}
```

In the interest of being thorough I will post this as well to show where I am getting my data back and how I am doing this...

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSError *error = nil;
// Get the JSON data from the website
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    for (NSArray *item in result) {
        NSArray *products = [item valueForKey:@"ProductDescription"];
        [dataArray addObject:products];
        [listOfItems addObject:products];
    }
}
else {
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

    for(NSDictionary *item in jsonDictionary)
        NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
}

[self performSelector:(@selector(refreshDisplay:)) withObject:(self.productsTableView) afterDelay:1.0];
NSLog(@"Finished");
}
```

My NSLog is here:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", dataArray);
return [dataArray count];
}
```

Comment: You need to post some more code, specifically, the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method for the second table.

Comment: Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath but I don't think that is the issue.  Like I said I see all the data returned without issue.  I think I have missed something with connecting the Products.xib with the dataArray that is returned in another function.

Comment: But you said you saw the expected data in a log statement not in your table, so that's why I thought the problem might be in this method. Did you log that from within this method?  If not, try logging cellValue to make sure the data is getting to that point in the program.

Comment: I added NSLog(@"Cell value: %@", cellValue); at the bottom of cellForRowAtIndexPath and I get back a (null) for each row.  So am I correct in assuming that although I am getting data back I am not connecting that data to the cellValue variable?  If so, how can I resolve this?

Comment: rdelmar, it appears that I was not referencing the correct variable.  I should have been looking at dataArray instead of listOfItems.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that logging listOfItems will also give you null. So, something's not connected corectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mixup...

```
  NSString *cellValue = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

instead of

```
  NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `products` (which is an `NSArray`) to `listOfItems`. Later in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you are saying `cellValue` (`NSString`) = `[listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` (which is potentially an `NSArray'). How would that work?